# Constructing LoaderManager for SQLite Database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listactivity, android-loadermanager

I am following this example: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

I am at this method:

```
// Called when a new Loader needs to be created
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    // Now create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of
    // creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.
    return new CursorLoader(this, ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
            PROJECTION, SELECTION, null, null);
}
```

I am trying to construct my own CursorLoader for a SQLite database. I have created earlier a subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper`. How do I get a URI to be used as a second argument of `CursorLoader` constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a `CursorLoader` to load data from your own SQLite database, then you must implement a [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) first. There are many good tutorials out there, form example [Writing your own Content Provider](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-writing-your-own-content-provider/) from Wolfram Rittmeyer's blog.

The URI in the example is from the [ContactsProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html).